# Как скрыть индексы датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def get():
    df = pd.DataFrame(exel())
    if df.empty:
        lable1['text'] = 'CОВПАДЕНИЙ НЕТ'
    else:
        lable1['text'] = df
```

Функция get реализует вывод нужной информации.
exel() возвращает список , который выводится через label.
Как убрать нумерацию строк и столбцов, которые выводятся вместе нужной информацией?

Comment: А что такое `lable1`? Датафрейм можно во-что нибудь преобразовать, например в список. Можно срендерить в `html`. Есть разные варианты. Но если просто вывести, то индексы всегда будут.

Comment: Label - это виджет, предназначенный для отображения какой-либо надписи без возможности редактирования пользователем. В окне кнопка. Нажав на неё срабатывае вышеуказанная функция. Просто я не знаю, как ещё можно вывести список в удобочитаемом виде в виджет.

Comment: Я список преобразовал в дата фрейм